# .NET Custom UserControl's contents are disappearing when the parent is resized

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, system.drawing

I have derived the .NET UserControl, to make my own PictureList class.
However, when I resize the parent of the control, the contents of the control disappear. No Resize event is issued or whatever. I left out code not relevant to the question.

```
    public ImageList(int width, int height)
    {
        ClientSize = new Size(width, height);
        ResizeRedraw = true;

    }


    // Ensure background transparency will be handled corretly.
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This messagebox is only shown upon the first drawing, but not after the magically disappearing of the contents");

        img = /*the image to draw*/
        rect = /*the size of the image*/
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rect);
    }
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error.  Also I do not know why on earth you have a MessageBox in OnPaint (hopefully just for abstract purposes).  Are you generating these controls programmatically, or with the designer?

Comment: I created it programmatically. The MessageBox is just for explanation purposes. The problem is, the control draws perfectly. I use it in the designer, place it in a layout, and anchor the layout to the form's sides. When I resize the form, the image just disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to enable `AutoRedraw`?

Comment: The AutoRedraw seems to be a property on the InkCollector, which I don't use. Do I need to?

Comment: No, there's something similar for Winforms controls, I'll update my answer once I find it.  (replied from memory before)